# Using MailMessage to send emails will raise the following errors "Mailbox unavailable" + "Error in processing. The server response"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, office365, mailmessage

I have the following code inside my asp.net console application to send an email using office 365 smtp server:-

```
static private void sendemail(ClientContext context, string subject, string body, string to)
        {
            using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
            {
                mail.From = new MailAddress("sharepoint@outorganization.com");
                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "ourorganization-com.mail.protection.outlook.com";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                mail.Body = body;
                mail.To.Add("***@****.net");   
                smtp.Port = 25;
                smtp.Send(mail);
            }

        } 

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "******";
            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (var cc in s)
                passWord.AppendChar(cc);
            using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://****.sharepoint.com/"))

            {

                context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("***@***.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);
                sendemail(context,"test 123","test123 body","***@***.net");

            }
        }
```

but the `smtp.Send(mail);` is raising the following errors, i got different errors depending on the server i am running the above code in:-

**Error-1**

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'Error in processing. The server response was: 4.4.62 Mail sent to the wrong Office 365 region. ATTR35. For more information please go to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865268 [HE1EUR01FT009.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.com]'
```

**Error-2**

```
Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Service unavailable, Client host [165.225.80.126] blocked using Spamhaus. To request removal from this list see https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/165.225.80.126 AS(1450) [VE1EUR01FT009.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.com]
```

any advice on this please?
Thanks

Comment: Does code work from home computer?  Does it fail on your company network?  Your company firewall is probably forwarding the SMTP port number to a proxy server and proxy is rejecting the email due to credentials failing.

Comment: @jdweng i tried on home and compnay PCs and i got `Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Service unavailable, Client host [165.225.80.126] blocked using Spamhaus. To request removal from this list see https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/165.225.80.126 AS(1450) [HE1EUR01FT033.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.com]'1`

Comment: Check the webpage of email server to find the SMTP settings.  The port could be wrong 25 (non secure), 465 (secure), 587 (secure) or the credentials could be wrong.  Your code is missing the credential which is the most likely reason for error.  Most email servers only accept the secure port number.

Comment: @jdweng ok will try changing the port... i i tried on another server and i got `System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'Error in processing. The server response was: 4.4.62 Mail sent to the wrong Office 365 region`

Comment: I've never used SMTP with Office 365.  The error looks like a Credential issue.  The username (and password) wasn't found in the Proxy mail address list.

Comment: @jdweng i updated my question with the full code to show how i am authenticating the request.. also when i tried ports `465 ` + `587` i got this error `SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 104.47.0.36:587
`

Comment: You are setting SSL (actually uses TLS).  YOu may also need to add System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;  The industry decided 5 years ago to obsolete TLS 1.0/1.1.  In June this year Microsoft pushed a security update on server to disable TLS 1.0/1.1.  So clients must use TLS 1.2/1.3.  Most versions of windows still default clients to TLS 1.1.  So in c# you must override the windows default and set version explicitly.

Comment: @jdweng but the same code worked well for another office 365 organization.. so not sure what is going on

Comment: The TLS version issue only start occurring after Microsoft pushed the security update.  So errors start occurring at different times when the update was installed. Sometimes it is months before a Microsoft update gets installed.  You can use a sniffer to see what version of TLS is being used.  The default version of TLS depends on the operating system when it is not specified in c#.

Comment: @jdweng ok i added this line of code `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` but i am still facing the same issues

Comment: `4.4.62 Mail sent to the wrong Office 365 region. ATTR35`